# digitalWrite giving different output voltages between programs

Tags: arduino-uno, digitalwrite

I'm using an arduino uno R3 for lighting a few LEDs in response to coputer control. I've written two programs, the first to try an Object Oriented style, and the second to split up the code into more manageable chunks. They both implement the same function, turning one led on, then off and repeat for the other led. I'd also put 100uF capacitors between the anode and ground of each led for a fade effect. When running with the first sketch this works fine, but I noticed with the second sketch, the fade no longer works and the leds are much brighter. There was no change in hardware between sketches, and reverting to either doesn't change anything. On inspection with a multimeter there appears to be a large difference in output voltage (1.6v -> 5.2v) between programs. I've tried changing pins and this seems to have no effect. Is it the code or have I missed something obvious with the hardware?

Program 1

```
#include "Arduino.h"
// create signal class
class two_aspect_signal {
  //store pin numbers
  const int danger_aspect;
  const int clear_aspect;

  public:
    two_aspect_signal(int danger_pin, int clear_pin):
      danger_aspect(danger_pin),
      clear_aspect(clear_pin)
    {}
    void setup(){
      //set to output
      pinMode(danger_aspect,OUTPUT);
      pinMode(clear_aspect,OUTPUT);
    }

    void danger(){
      //turn red light on, green light off
      digitalWrite(danger_aspect,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(clear_aspect,LOW);
    }

    void cleaR(){
      //turn red light off, green light on
      digitalWrite(danger_aspect,LOW);
      digitalWrite(clear_aspect,HIGH);
    }
};
//create signal object
two_aspect_signal sig(7,8);
void setup() {
}
void loop() {
  //turn red light on, green off
  sig.danger();
  delay(2000);
  //turn green light on, red light off
  sig.cleaR();
  delay(2000);
}
```

Program 2

```
#include "sig2.h"
//create signal object
two_aspect sig(7,8);
void setup(){}
void loop() {
  // set red light on, green off
  sig.danger();
  delay(2000);
  // set green on, red off
  sig.cleaR();
  delay(2000);
}
```

Program 2 (sig2.cpp)

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "sig2.h"

two_aspect::two_aspect(int clear_pin, int danger_pin)
{
  //set pins to output and store
  pinMode(danger_pin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clear_pin,OUTPUT);
  _danger_pin = danger_pin;
  _clear_pin = clear_pin;
}

void two_aspect::danger()
{
  //set red light on, green off
  digitalWrite(_danger_pin,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(_clear_pin,LOW);
}
void two_aspect::cleaR()
{
  //set green led on, red led off
  digitalWrite(_danger_pin,LOW);
  digitalWrite(_clear_pin,HIGH);
}
```

Program 2 (sig2.h)

```
#ifndef sig2_h
#define sig2_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class two_aspect
{
  public:
    two_aspect(int clear_pin, int danger_pin);
    void danger();
    void cleaR();
  private:
    int _clear_pin;
    int _danger_pin;
};

#endif
```

Please let me know if this should've been in the electronics forum, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is, that in your first sketch you never call `two_aspect_signal.setup()`, thus the pins are never set as output. By default pins are configured as inputs. Doing `digitalWrite()` while the pin is configured as input will enable or disable the internal pullup resistor of that pin.

So in your first sketch you are powering the LEDs through the internal pullup resistor (if I correctly remember about 10kOhm). Thus they are rather dim. Also it takes some time for the capacitor to be charged through the big pullup resistor.

In your second sketch you configure the pins as output. So the LEDs will now  be actively driven through the pins output driver. It can provide way more current than the pullup resistor, thus the LEDs light up brigther. And the bigger current can also charge the capacitor in way less time (a time so small, that you don't even see it). Thus you don't see any fading (the fading is there, but just too fast for your eyes).

**What to do know?** You can of course just use the pullup resistor (and not configuring the pins as output). Or you can configure the pins as outputs and add a current limiting resistor between the pin and the LED/capacitor bundle. With your second sketch and the current circuit you are risking to damage the output drivers of that pin (through the LED current and through the high inrush current until the capacitor is charged). The sizing of that resistor depends on your needs. Make sure, that the current never exceeds 20mA (sustainable pin max current) (for 5V this would be R=U/I=5V/20mA=250Ohm as minimum resistance). The higher the resistance, the dimmer the LED will be and the longer the capacitor needs to charge. After that you can also change the capacitance. The higher the capacitance, the longer it will take to charge it (so longer fade effect).

Comment: Thank you! I'd put a 1k resistor before ground and thought that would be enough, I've now put 10k resistors on the outputs and it works great.